# MySQL database design - Check in system

Tags: php, mysql

I am hoping to get a little bit of database design knowledge from you :)

I am attempting to build a check-in system for an office building.

What happens is:

1. a Code is called about a bomb threat in building A.
2. a designated user is supposed to sweep the one or more areas assigned to them.
3. a user will then check in for their area(s). (not checked, checked - no problem, checked - problem)

I will need to build an interface that will pull all incoming submissions.

```
Users
---------------
id | name | username | password

Buildings
---------------
id | name

Sections
---------------
id | building_id | name

Assignments
---------------
id | section_id | user_id
```

So this overall design works to assign users to sections (many to many) and sections to buildings (one to one)

What I am having an issue with is storing the actually submissions while being able to easily retrieve them later.

I want to be able to store submissions in a way that would allow for a user to update an answer. View old answer. Submit a new answer.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add a table Submission (id, user_id, building_id, section_id, timestamp, check_result)

Comment: Should `Sections.name` be `Sections.user_id`? And do you need a *history* of submissions, or only view and/or change the last result?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I need a history of submissions. Sections.name is just a label for it. the user is assigned in Assignments table.

Comment: @hol does repeating the section_id and building_id go against best practices? I'm pretty new to db design.

Comment: Yes and no. I would log the submissions, that is for sure. But looking it over I think we should connect the submission to an assignment if the submission matches by section_id and user_id. For practical use I am missing the bomb threat table so that the assignment is related to a actual threat and the submission is not assigned to a stone age old assignment. But to stay high level: Log the submissions, relate them to an assignment. So add assignment_id to the submission table and add "executed" field to the assignments table.

Comment: Name your id columns the same in every table in which they are used. Also, name each table for the (singular) entity that's in each row.  For example, users.id should be named user.user_id.  This will help various tools like the MySQL Workbench understand what you're doing, and simplify your maintenance tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need an incident and response table.

Incident would be date-time and any detail (bomb threat - look for backpack).

When an incident is entered the system should prefill the response table, all assignments with a response value of not checked. As each person responds you add their response, and date time of the response. You know what hasn't been checked yet by running a query on that and pulling the max response datetime grouped by assignmentID, filtered by incident.

Afterwards you can run logs on all the responses to analyse things like who responded the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

From where you're at, I would add a table of reports, for the reports that come in which require responses. This would include an ID of course, date/time field for when the report was made, a status field (e.g., report received, report determined not to require response, response in progress, emergency services contacted, response complete), and probably a short field for the title of the incident ("Bomb threat") and a free-text field for a description ("Unknown male caller phoned the front desk at 10:23 AM MDT and stated that a large bomb had been placed in the building of basement B. Report received from front desk receptionist J. Random at 10:28 AM.")

You'd then also need an answer table. This would consist of, at minimum, its own unique ID, the incident ID, the user ID of the user making the response, the section ID being responded to, the date/time at which the response was recorded, a "response type" field (e.g., response pending, response in progress, no issue found, potential issue found/recommend emergency services contact), and a free-text field allowing the responder to input more detail on their response.

Since this is a log of an emergency response, you may want to consider having amendments/supplements on additional records to reflect updates rather than overwriting or updating existing ones, but that's up to you and your users' requirements. This system would allow you to do direct updates by record as well, and either way would easily allow you to pull up a log of the user's previous responses to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the addition of the following tables:

a) threats

- id
- threatdate
- description
- other columns to capture the metadata for the threat

b) threatstatus

- id
- threat_id
- checker_id (the person who checks may not always be the one who is assigned)
- section_id
- status
- datechecked (assuming that it may not always be the same day also catering for midnight checks), notes (if any),
- building_id (this column is duplicated to speed up lookups so that you do not have to join to sections to find the building)